# Gatsby - After `success Build manifest and related icons` - manifest file, icons get deleted on ` Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles`

Tags: node.js, gatsby, manifest, gatsby-plugin

I am using Gatsby version `v4.23.x` and I am facing an issue where upon running the build for gatsby.

- The build generates a `manifest.webmanifest` and `icons` folder
- Post a message of `success Build manifest and related icons` and then execute  `Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles` after 10 seconds the `manifest.webmanifest` and `icons` folder is deleted as if they were never present

I did not receive any warnings/errors.

Currently, i have manually generated a `manifest.webmanifest` and then i run copy command to past it to public folder location (Not a recommended approach)

I have plugins installed in the below order in `gatsby-config`

`gatsby-plugin-manifest`
`gatsby-plugin-offline`
`gatsby-plugin-pwainstall`

All the above 3 plugins are at the end of the file, no other plugins after these!

Does anyone know what this behaviour is or it is a bug in Gatsby build?